# How to dismiss the actionsheet in tableviewcell when i tap on the view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, uiactionsheet

Here is my Code.Am very new to Xcode.When i tap on tableview cell am getting UIActionSheet.To dismiss UIActionSheet i used UITapGestureRecognizer.It's not Working for me.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    NSLog(@"cell text label =%@",lbl.text);
    _StoreNameobj = lbl.text;


    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Store Maintenance Action"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Show Store Details",@"Navigate to Store",@"Edit Store Nickname",@"Delete Store", nil];


    actionSheet.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOut:)];
    [lbl addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
}

    - (void)tapOut{
    //dismiss the action sheet here
    [actionSheet removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Any Help is Appreciable.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: why cant you use `didSelectRow` or `UIButton` to dismiss

Comment: There is no need to take tap gesture on action sheet. It's default behavior is dismiss it on click.

Comment: How to use didSelectRow to dismiss ActionSheet @Shubhank

Comment: try coming to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I think you not need to manually remove the actionsheet. By default actionsheet resigns on click. there is no need to take tab gesture i think.

Show actionsheet like,

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

so when you clik on any button it will dissmiss automatically

Answer (score 0):

To view UIActionSheet on UITableViewCell apply this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                        @"button title1", nil];

  [popup show];
}
```

add TapGesture

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapp = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HideActionSheet:)];

        [tapp setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        tapp.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        [self.view.window tapp];
        [tapp release];
}
```

HideActionSheet code:

```
- (void) HideActionSheet:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
     { 
       CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:nil];  
        if (![self.view pointInside:[self.view convertPoint:location fromView:self.view.window] withEvent:nil]) 
        {
          [self.view.window removeGestureRecognizer:sender];
          [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: i should implement above code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath or cellForRowAtIndexpath tableview methods @Pratap

Comment: check updated answer create tapgesture in ViewDidLoad

Comment: I need Actionsheet when i click on tableview cell @Pratap

Comment: please check again

Comment: Without adding cancel title i need to dismiss ActionSheet @pratap

Comment: please check this code in this code i put destructiveButtonTitle to nil